# If $(element).text() Is In String

Tags: javascript, jquery

### What I'm doing...

I would like to have a string as such:

```
var match = "abcd|efhi|jklm|nopq|rstu|vwxyz";
```

And then check whether `$(element).text()` is one of the `match.split("|")` or simply within `match`.

I thought I'd be able to do `if($('element').text().toLowerCase().match(/^(match)$/)) {` however this wouldn't work.

### Question

Why doesn't my `match()` work and what is my best way to resolve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best way to resolve is to assign a regex to match

```
var match = /^(abcd|efhi|jklm|nopq|rstu|vwxyz)$/i;
```

Note that I added `i` for case insensitivity, so you can get rid of `toLowerCase()`

```
if($('element').text().match(match)) {
     //...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My approach without using RegEx

```
var match = "abcd|efhi|jklm|nopq|rstu|vwxyz".split('|');    
if (match.indexOf($('element').text().toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
    // match found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To match a variable string, you can create a Regexp object:

```
var match = "^(abcd|efhi|jklm|nopq|rstu|vwxyz)$";
var reg = new RegExp(match, 'g');
if($('element').text().toLowerCase().match(reg)) {}
```

To make it case insensitive:

```
var match = "^(abcd|efhi|jklm|nopq|rstu|vwxyz)$";
var reg = new RegExp(match, 'ig');
if($('element').text().match(reg)){}
```